# How to integrate mysql or mongodb to grails 3.2.10

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, grails, database-connection

I'm about start with a web application project and I am trying to integrate Mysql into Grails 3. All of the online tutorials show us to change the DataSource file which does not currently (there is Application.yml).

I tried changing the Application.yml as given in the official documentation, but it gives me a big error. Its a new project and has no other changes to it. I've used grails 2.4 previously, it was really easy with that and now I'm thinking of changing back.

Change:

```
dataSource :
pooled : true
dbCreate : "update"
url : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_database"
driverClassName : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
dialect : org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
username : "username"
password : "password"
properties :
   jmxEnabled : true
   initialSize : 5
   maxActive : 50
   minIdle : 5
   maxIdle : 25
   maxWait : 10000
   maxAge : 10 * 60000
   timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis : 5000
   minEvictableIdleTimeMillis : 60000
   validationQuery : "SELECT 1"
   validationQueryTimeout : 3
   validationInterval : 15000
   testOnBorrow : true
   testWhileIdle : true
   testOnReturn : false
   jdbcInterceptors : "ConnectionState;StatementCache(max=200)"
   defaultTransactionIsolation : 
java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

the error I get:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -XX:+TieredCompilation -
XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -XX:CICompilerCount=3 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -
classpath /home/nischit/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-
2.1/org.grails/grails-
shell/3.2.10/c6b000bbb8ac369a9be062f08e8a0a8d3f85705/grails-shell-            
3.2.10.jar:/home/nischit/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-
2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-
simple/1.7.25/8dacf9514f0c707cbbcdd6fd699e8940d42fb54e/slf4j-simple-
1.7.25.jar:/home/nischit/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-
2.1/org.codehaus.plexus/plexus-component-api/1.0-alpha-
33/7d9560effcadf867937ac6885d0d1045ea98ab59/plexus-component-api-1.0-
alpha-33.jar:/home/nischit/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files


Running application...
2017-10-02 01:42:14.120 ERROR --- [ost-startStop-1] 
o.s.b.c.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter    : Error starting Tomcat 
context. Exception: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: 
Error creating bean with name 'grailsCacheFilter': Cannot create 
inner bean '(inner bean)#17d4fdc1' of type
[grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.
simple.MemoryPageFragmentCachingFilter] 
while setting bean property 'filter'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#17d4fdc1': Unsatisfied 
dependency expressed through method 'setUrlMappingsHandlerMapping' 
parameter 0; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsHandlerMapping': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 
'setWebRequestInterceptors' parameter 0; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'openSessionInViewInterceptor': Cannot 
resolve reference to bean 'hibernateDatastore' while setting bean 
property 'hibernateDatastore'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via 
constructor failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to 
instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: 
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to 
bean 'dataSourceLazy' while setting constructor argument; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Cannot resolve 
reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor 
argument; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:388)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:375)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at 
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.
defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'grailsCacheFilter': Cannot create 
inner bean '(inner bean)#17d4fdc1' of type 
[grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.simple.
MemoryPageFragmentCachingFilter] while setting bean property 
'filter'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#17d4fdc1': Unsatisfied 
dependency expressed through method 'setUrlMappingsHandlerMapping' 
parameter 0; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsHandlerMapping': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 
'setWebRequestInterceptors' parameter 0; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'openSessionInViewInterceptor': Cannot 
resolve reference to bean 'hibernateDatastore' while setting bean 
property 'hibernateDatastore'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via 
constructor failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to 
instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: 
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to 
bean 'dataSourceLazy' while setting constructor argument; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Cannot resolve 
reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor 
argument; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error c 
reating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Initialization of bean 
failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert 
property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long' for 
property 'maxAge'; nested exception is 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10*60000"
at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.
BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean
(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#17d4fdc1': Unsatisfied 
dependency expressed through method 'setUrlMappingsHandlerMapping' 
parameter 0; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsHandlerMapping': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 
'setWebRequestInterceptors' parameter 0; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'openSessionInViewInterceptor': Cannot 
resolve reference to bean 'hibernateDatastore' while setting bean 
property 'hibernateDatastore'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via 
constructor failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to 
instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: 
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to 
bean 'dataSourceLazy' while setting constructor argument; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Cannot resolve 
reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor 
argument; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Initialization of bean 
failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert 
property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long' for 
property 'maxAge'; nested exception is 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10*60000"
at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.
AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
$AutowiredMethodElement.inject
(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:667)
Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsHandlerMapping': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 
'setWebRequestInterceptors' parameter 0; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'openSessionInViewInterceptor': Cannot 
resolve reference to bean 'hibernateDatastore' while setting bean 
property 'hibernateDatastore'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via 
constructor failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to 
instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: 
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to 
bean 'dataSourceLazy' while setting constructor argument; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Cannot resolve 
reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor 
argument; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Initialization of bean 
failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert 
property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long' for 
property 'maxAge'; nested exception is 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10*60000"

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with 
non-zero exit value 1
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info 
or --debug option to get more log output.
| Error Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full 
trace)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the way you're trying to set the maxAge value on your data source:

> Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to
>   required type 'long' for property 'maxAge'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10*60000"

Try just setting a concrete value rather than a calculation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not very comfortable with YML standard then simply create a new file with name `application.groovy`, place it inside the `conf` directory and add the datasource block in that groovy file. Don't forget to remove the data source block from `application.yml` file.

Comment: I ended up using reactjs with python backend instead due to persistent long  error..